# bounty not awarded

Tags: support

I answers this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494591/how-to-use-retrofit-as-a-singleton-while-using-gson-covertor/33494767#33494767) before the op started the bounty and after couple of edits he accepted the answer. At the end of the grace period the bounty wasn't awarded. is it the expected behavior? IMO the accepted answer should be always automatically be awarded if the bounty wasn't manually awarded. A
ny thoughts?

Comment: The bounty was started after you posted your answer. It is not eligible for the automatic award.

Comment: The point of the bounty is to get *additional* attention (and, hopefully, answers), so to award it to answers that were already there seems counter-productive.

Comment: It is kind of a silly rule.  But I suppose it is necessary to prevent some users from posting a sloppy answer and only finish it later when it is bountied.  My call: it should still be awarded if the OP edited the question.  Hard sell.

Comment: I thought that accepted answers were treated differently. my bad.

Answer (score 9):

From the MSE [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> #### What is automatic awarding?
>
> [Approximately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147576/bounty-not-awarded-after-the-end-of-the-grace-period/147577#147577) 24 hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically.
>
> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty (provided that the answer was posted during the bounty period).  Answers accepted before the bounty period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.
>
> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is awarded *half* the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given *after* the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any answer, and is *not* refunded to the bounty starter.

So in your case, you posted it **before** the bounty, as such, it is not eligible for an automatic award, regardless of it meeting any other criteria.